# Several Intersection Observers tracking different elements merged into a single one

Tags: javascript

I have a simple code using the IntersectionObserver, that basically tells when an object is visible on the screen, when that happens I want a title to change to the same name of that visible element. The thing is that I've created 5 different variables for each observer related to each of the 5 upcoming areas. Is there a way to simplify this code?

Right now it works but seems to be wrong to me and I cannot figure out how to merge them all.

Thanks in advance!!

```js
var observer = new IntersectionObserver(function(entries) {
    if(entries[0].isIntersecting === true)
        document.querySelector(".productTitle").innerHTML = "Logotype";
}, { threshold: [1] });

var observer1 = new IntersectionObserver(function(entries) {
    if(entries[0].isIntersecting === true)
        document.querySelector(".productTitle").innerHTML = "Branding";
}, { threshold: [1] });

var observer2 = new IntersectionObserver(function(entries) {
    if(entries[0].isIntersecting === true)
        document.querySelector(".productTitle").innerHTML = "Website Dev.";
}, { threshold: [1] });

var observer3 = new IntersectionObserver(function(entries) {
    if(entries[0].isIntersecting === true)
        document.querySelector(".productTitle").innerHTML = "3d Modeling";
}, { threshold: [1] });

var observer4 = new IntersectionObserver(function(entries) {
    if(entries[0].isIntersecting === true)
        document.querySelector(".productTitle").innerHTML = "Vectorial Work";
}, { threshold: [1] });

observer.observe(document.querySelector("#visibleLogo"));
observer1.observe(document.querySelector("#visibleBranding"));
observer2.observe(document.querySelector("#visibleWeb"));
observer3.observe(document.querySelector("#visible3d"));
observer4.observe(document.querySelector("#visibleVector"));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Assign a common class like `.page` to your articles Elements
- You need only one IntersectionObserver instance, and you can attach it to all the desired `.page` inside a`.forEach()`.
- Use `data-*` attribute to store the desired title in the HTML itself like i.e: `data-title="Title to show when in viewport"`

```js
const elTitle = document.querySelector(".productTitle");

const pageInViewport = (entries, observer) => {
  entries.forEach(entry => {
    if (entry.isIntersecting) {
      elTitle.textContent = entry.target.dataset.title;
    }
  });
};

const pageObs = new IntersectionObserver(pageInViewport);
const obsOptions = {threshold: [1]};

// Attach observer to every .page element:
document.querySelectorAll('.page')
  .forEach(EL => pageObs.observe(EL, obsOptions));
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.productTitle {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  background: gold;
}

.page {
  padding: 30px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<div class="productTitle"></div>

<div class="page" id="visibleLogo" data-title="Logotype">visibleLogo</div>
<div class="page" id="visibleBranding" data-title="Branding">visibleBranding</div>
<div class="page" id="visibleWeb" data-title="Website Dev.">visibleWeb</div>
<div class="page" id="visible3d" data-title="3d Modeling">visible3d</div>
<div class="page" id="visibleVector" data-title="Vectorial Work">visibleVector</div>
```

Comment: tanks @Roko C. Buljan but for example, I won't be changing only the title, because I'm also updating content, images and price. Basically there's a slider that contains the word/services and whenever each word appear on screen (one at a time) then everything else below that (title, description, images, price) updates. so with data-title within each div then I'm stuck to that right? Sorry I think I wasn't that specific at the very beginning!

Comment: @Eu2019 I don't know where do you want to store that data. In an Object? If that's the case, instead of using `data-title` and respectively `entry.target.dataset.title` use instead: `data[el.target.id].title` given you have some data like: `const data = {visibleLogo: {title:"LOGO", image:"foo", "content:"bar"}}`